# SQL subquery or JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables,i'm using mysql and php and the structure look like this

```
Table A(Job ads)
id_job
title_job
description_job

Table B(Applicants)
id_applicant
id_job
ID
date_application
```

so for example I need to show every job ad and its applicants which can be 0 or more.

so I'd like to display a link called "Display applicants"(and the number of applicants here as a preview).

I tried JOIN but got records from the same job for every applicant.if i had 2 applicants for a job , then i got the job record listed twice. 
 do i need a subquery inside the main query to get the number of applicants to a specified job ad ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, you need to count the number of applicants and group by the job:

```
SELECT id_job,
       title_job, 
       description_job, 
       count(id_applicant) 
FROM `Table A` 
INNER JOIN `Table B` 
ON `Table A`.id_job = `Table B`.id_job 
GROUP BY id_job, title_job, description_job
```